# Llamar una vista parcial desde un botón

Tags: c#, html, html5, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Estoy trabajando con ASP.NET MVC con Bootstrap y quiero llamar a una vista parcial desde un botón, mi código es el siguiente:

```
<div class="container">
    <h3>Index</h3>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" name="btnMantenimiento" onclick="enviar('Details.cshtml')">Boton</button>     
</div>
```

Comment: quieres realizarlo mediante ajax o si el boton realiza un submit al servidor tambien es valido ? en que luegar se renderizaria esta vista parcial ? seria dentro del div del container ?

Comment: Hola Leandro, sería por ajax, sobre renderizar tengo un index en el cual por medio de un botón llamo a un popoup eso sería mi vista parcial

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La estructura de archivos en esta respuesta es:

1. Controller/HomeController.cs
2. Views/Home/Detalles.cshtml

**En tu controlador:**

```
 public ActionResult Detalles()
    {
        return PartialView();
    }
```

**En la vista de donde quieres llamar:**

**Actualización**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="llamarVistaParcial();" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" >
La llamada ganadora a la vista parcial
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div id="resultado"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<script>
function llamarVistaParcial() {
    var laURLDeLaVista = '@Url.Action("Detalles", "Home")';
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        async: true,
        type: "GET",
        url: laURLDeLaVista,
        data: {},
        success: function (response) {
            $('#resultado').html('');
            $('#resultado').html(response);
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: Gracias por responder fredyfx, ya esta llamando a la vista parcial, pero lo quiero llamar como popoup tengo un js para eso pero no se en que parte del código puedo poner este fragmento de código.

Comment: de nada @PedroÁvila acabo de actualizar la respuesta, espero te sea de utilidad, sigue con todo el power 2.0 al desarrollo!

Comment: Hola fredyfx, ya puedo llamar al formulario partial pero tengo un js para ese fin y no se como utilizarlo, tengo otra pregunta en este foro donde explico que necesito. http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/5465/al-llamar-a-un-formulario-se-debe-convertir-en-popoup?noredirect=1#comment9942_5465

Comment: fredyfx, el script es a continuación del modal?

Comment: puede estar antes o después, no hay problema; el hecho es que al hacer click en el botón llamará a la función :)

Comment: fredyfx, y si hago click en un @Html.ActionLink("Detalle", "Details", new {id = item.PhoneId}) por intermedio de un if porque esta create y delete como le digo si hice click en detalle haga el sript del modal

Comment: http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/5673/como-hacer-un-if-al-pool-de-create-detalle-y-delete

Comment: a ver @PedroÁvila espero esto te sea de utilidad: http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/5792/822 dale con todo el power al desarrollo! Gracias por preguntar, sé que más personas andan con la misma preguntas y ojala este ejemplo ayude a aclarar ideas :)

Comment: Buenas Tardes: Aplique todo pero no me muestra la partialView en el Modal, me hara falta algo.

Comment: buenas tardes @CarlosAlbertoHernndezRincn, te recomiendo que publiques tu pregunta junto con el código que tienes, entre todos en la comunidad te ayudamos a resolver :D