# Al llamar a un formulario se debe convertir en popoup

Tags: javascript, c#, html5, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

Estoy trabajando con ASP MVC, llamo a una vista parcial que debe convertirse en *popoup*, lo llamo desde un botón desde mi vista `index`, el código es el siguiente:

```
@Model OperacionesCrudMVC.Models.Phone

<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h3 class="modal-title">Phone Detail</h3>
</div>

<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => Model.Model, new { @class = "control-label col-sm-3" })
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Model, new { @class = "form-control required", @disabled = "disabled" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => Model.Company, new { @class = "control-label col-sm-3" })
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Company, new { @class = "form-control required", @disabled = "disabled" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => Model.Price, new { @class = "control-label col-sm-3" })
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Price, new { @class = "form-control required", @disabled = "disabled" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

    <div id='myModal' class='modal fade in'>
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div id='myModalContent'></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    @section scripts{
        <script type="text/javascript" src="~/scripts/Appjs/phones.js"></script>
    }
</div>
```

Tengo un .js que me imagino lo hace popup:

```
$(function () {
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
$("a[data-modal]").on("click", function (e) {        
    $('#myModalContent').load(this.href, function () {
        $('#myModal').modal({
            keyboard: true
        }, 'show');
        bindForm(this);
    });
    return false;
function bindForm(dialog) {
$('form', dialog).submit(function () {
    $('#progress').show();
    $.ajax({
        url: this.action,
        type: this.method,
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function (result) {
            if (result.success) {
                $('#myModal').modal('hide');
                $('#progress').hide();
                location.reload();
            } else {
                $('#progress').hide();
                $('#myModalContent').html(result);
                bindForm();
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
});
}
```

Comment: edita la pregunta porque el codigo queo aml formateado. Ademas como implementas el popup, usas alguna libreria ?

Comment: Uso un js y ese código que dice <div class="modal-footer">

Comment: Algún administrador que pueda corregir mi pregunta por favor tengo problemas al pegar el código no sale todo en el formato adecuado.

Comment: @PedroÁvila puedas editar el post pulsando en el enlace "editar" localizado en la parte inferior izquierda de la pregunta

Comment: Gracias Alvaro.

Comment: @PedroÁvila el html que muestras es de la pagina index ?  Veo que controlas el submit, pero no veo que definas en el html ningun tag form

Comment: Lenadro, la pagina que muestro es mi vista Detail parcial, el index es otra vista que por medio de un botón llamo a esta vistaDetail, la quiero llamar como popoup

Comment: por lo que veo, estas en un modal o popup. Dentro de la función **success** de tu ajax estás ocultando el modal donde estas, también hace un refresh a la pagina  en caso la informacion llegue exitosamente, y si no, el progress se oculta y el contenido se muestra en el myModalContent.

Comment: fredyfx, esta es mi vista parcial Detail la cual se tiene que mostrar cuando llamo desde el index con el botón, pero la ultima parte del código creo va en el botón donde hago el llamado a esta vista partial?

Comment: @PedroÁvila, dale una visita a este enlace: http://www.bootply.com/86973 hay un ejemplo de como llamar a otro modal dentro de uno utilizando bootstrap 3. Que error te sale cuando tratas de llamar a la vista?

Comment: Estoy usando este. http://www.advancesharp.com/blog/1126/search-sort-paging-insert-update-and-delete-with-asp-net-mvc-and-bootstrap-modal-popup-part-2

Comment: No me sale ningún error, solo que quiero hacerlo de la manera que esta en ese link que pase.

Comment: Yo hago algo muy similar pero todo el código es en función de bootstrap modal en una vista tengo todo el contenido del modal y en el index únicamente tengo un div al presionar x boton me carga el modal y lo cargo con `$('#modal').load('modal/formModal', function(){$('#modal').modal('show')});`

Comment: lograste hacerlo funcionar @PedroÁvila ?

Comment: Asi es @fredyfx ya hace buen tiempo

Comment: excelente! me había parecido que la respuesta de @LeandroTuttini no había sido aceptada. saludos :D

Comment: Como tengo tantos post no había fijado de marcar como respuesta, gracias @fredyfx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entiendo deberias realizar dos operaciones

- definir el div como un popup
- cargar el html del partial de forma dinamica

Analiza el ejemplo

[Render a partial view inside a Jquery modal popup on top of a parent view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20923305/render-a-partial-view-inside-a-jquery-modal-popup-on-top-of-a-parent-view)

Entonces define el popup usando algo como ser

```
$("#myModal").dialog({
    autoOpen: true,
    modal: true,
    open: function () {
        $(this).load('@Url.Action("NombreAction", "NombreController")');
    },
    buttons: {
        "Aceptar": function () {
            //codigo
        },
        Cancel: function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
});
```

La carga de contenido del div es simple por medio de la linea

```
$(this).load('@Url.Action("NombreAction", "NombreController")');
```

recuerda definir el action que devuelve el partial que estarias volcando dentro del div.

No se necesitas una llamada ajax para cargar el div